# Unable to get copy text into clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this for copying text into clipboard..

```
http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/
```

I have tried like this, but I am unable to get the copied text into clipboard..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.zclip.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){


        $('textarea#showthis').zclip({
            path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy:function(){return $('#showthis').val();}
        });


    });

    function myfunc2()
    {
         var selectedobj=document.getElementById('showthis');

        if(selectedobj.className=='hide')
        {  //check if classname is hide 
            selectedobj.style.display = "block";
            selectedobj.readOnly=true;
            selectedobj.className ='show';
         } else {
            selectedobj.style.display = "none";
            selectedobj.className ='hide';
         }
    }
</script>
 </head>

 <body>
   <label onclick="myfunc2()">Click here</label>
   <textarea id="showthis" style="display:none" class="hide"  readonly>hi, how are you?</textarea>
 </body>
</html>
```

Please tell me what went wrong! (I am not aware of javascript and jquery stuff!)

Comment: do you have something like flashblock enabled? Do you have a flash-plugin installed?

Comment: Also, read this: https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04a.html

Comment: May I know is it working for you..? I mean my above code..

Comment: I am at work, I don't have flash :D

Comment: As I mentioned above that Iam using this code: http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/ , so just by looking at my above code, do you think that I need to make any tweaks to make it work? and how do i check whether my chrome already installed flash or not? as far as I knew, flash is installed in my PC..

Comment: Chrome has flash per default, if I'm not mistaken. However, I can't see a mistake in the code. I guess it's a flash-issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function myfunc2() {
   if($('#showthis').css('display') == 'none'){
    $('#showthis').show().removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
  }else{
    $('#showthis').hide().removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! BUT Clipboard functionality not working for me.. Any idea on this..?